# how to get the location(lat/lng) on google maps v3 from the location(x,y)

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, location

i have the  (x,y)

```
(event.pageX-$("#map_canvas").offset().left,event.pageY-$("#map_canvas").offset().top)
```

but how to get the (lat,lng)

thanks

Answer (score 4):

In your initialize function for a map define:

```
var overlay;
overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
overlay.draw = function() {};
overlay.setMap(map);
```

Next when you want to get the location run:

```
var point=new google.maps.Point(x,y);
var location=$overlay.getProjection().fromContainerPixelToLatLng(point);
```

Best
K

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code that doesn't rely on OverlayView(). This method makes use of the built in fromPointToLatLng() method in the maps API.

```
function pixelToLatlng(xcoor, ycoor) {
  var ne = map.getBounds().getNorthEast();
  var sw = map.getBounds().getSouthWest();
  var projection = map.getProjection();
  var topRight = projection.fromLatLngToPoint(ne);
  var bottomLeft = projection.fromLatLngToPoint(sw);
  var scale = 1 << map.getZoom();

  var newLatlng = projection.fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(xcoor / scale + bottomLeft.x, ycoor / scale + topRight.y));
  return newLatlng;
};
```

Source:
http://magicalrosebud.com/how-to-use-googlemaps-api-frompointtolatlng/

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mhaq865o/5/

Answer (score 0):

Enter left and top pixel offset (x,y) and it returns a `google.maps.LatLng`

```
function PixelToLatLng(x,y){
    var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView()
    overlay.setMap(map);
    var LatLng = overlay.getProjection().fromContainerPixelToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(x,y));        
    overlay.setMap(null); delete overlay;
    return LatLng;
}
```

Surprised this isn't in the `google.maps.Map` object.

Comment: How does this differ from the previous answer?

Comment: Clean simple function which doesn't leave an overlay on the map.