# Load parts data for Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use google maps v3 api.
I have many markers and i want to load their by some parts.
I create new mapType (google.maps.ImageMapType).
In **getTileUrl** method i have receive current zoom and x,y coordinates.

```js
var myMapTypeOptions = {
  getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
       //coord.x
       //coord.y
       //convert x,y,zoom to LatLng
       //make request to server with LatLng
  },
  tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256)
};
```

How i can get **LatLng** of tile from x,y coordinates.
I saw example http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/
but it based on ver.2

Maybe exists another way to solve my problem?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567639/how-to-get-the-locationlat-lng-on-google-maps-v3-from-the-locationx-y

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)

Comment: Some solution:
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17278/calculate-lat-lon-bounds-for-individual-tile-generated-from-gdal2tiles/17289#17289